# Initial and final topologies

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $X_i$ are topological spaces, and $X_i \xrightarrow{f_i} Y$ are a family of maps into the set $Y$. The final topology on $Y$ is defined to be the finest topology on $Y$ such that each $f_i$ is continuous.

I have also heard it described as "the topology on $Y$ consisting of the images of saturated open sets in $X_i$", but it seems this requires that every $y\in Y$ is in the image of some $X_i$. It also makes sense that we would mostly be interested in the final topology when $Y = \cup_i f_i(X_i)$; otherwise we just have this chunk of $Y$ hanging around with the discrete topology on it.

Dually, suppose we have $X \xrightarrow{g_i} Y_i$ and we want to give $X$ the initial topology. Now is there some reason why $g_i$ should separate points? (I think this would be the dual requirement to $Y$ being the image.) Maybe if it does not, then points not separated are topologically indistinguishable? Would we ever care about the initial topology with respect to a single map which was not injective?

The separating points reminds me of the [characterization](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology#Separating_points_from_closed_sets) of initial topologies as separating points from closed sets

Comment: You are right. If $(g_i)_i$ does not separate points, then the topology on the subspace of points which are not separated would be the indiscrete one, kind of dual to the fact that the topology on the subspace of points not assumed by any function $f_i$ would be the discrete one.